# Flexdashboards : is the original dataframe used to create tables/graphs secure?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, flexdashboard

I am very sorry if this is a stupid question,

I was wondering… let’s say you have an HTML file created from R Markdown containing some graph. More specifically, this HTML document is a flexdashboard. Is it possible to obtain the original dataframe used to create the graph, using only this HTML file?

I don’t know if I managed to explain, but I am worried about the security of the original dataframe.

I suppose the real question is, how does Markdown knit the R chunks? Is it only the outcome of the code that is incorporated in the HTML document... or is it everything? I always thought that because knitr create a .md temporary file that contains the code and its outcomes that meant that it only contained the code and the outcomes and not the original dataframe used to make graphs, stats, tables, etc. But I may be completely wrong and I wish to know the truth.

If anybody has the answer (and maybe some tips in how to secure the flexdashboards), I would be very thankful. I hope I managed to explain my problem in a comprehensible way.